# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, html, go

I am running a server on go. When I access the `localhost:8888/static/ajax.html`, 
I get no errors. But when I just access `localhost:8888` I get 
an error saying:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token <"

By default "/" serves ajax.html file, but doing so I don't get the 
expected result. On the other hand on calling `/static/ajax.html` I am 
getting the expected result without any errors.

**server.go** contains the following :

```
package main 
import ( 
        "http" 
        "flag" 
) 
//var path = flag.String("storage", "/home/chinmay/work/jstree/", "Set storage directory, use absolute path") 
var root = flag.String("root", "/home/chinmay/work/ajax/", "Set root directory, use absolute path") 
func temp(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){ 
        http.ServeFile(w,r,*root +"ajax.html") 
} 

func main(){ 
        http.HandleFunc("/", temp) 
        http.Handle("/static/", http.FileServer(*root, "/static/")) 
        http.ListenAndServe(":8888", nil) 
}
```

**ajax.html** contains the following:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/three/Three.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/Detector.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/RequestAnimationFrame.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/Stats.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $.ajaxSetup ({ 
                cache:false; 
            }) 

            $("#container").ready(function(){ 
                $("button").click(function(){ 
                    $.getScript("model.js"); 
                }); 
            }); 
        </script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <button>Use Ajax to get and then run a JavaScript</button> 
        <div id="container"> 
        </div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

socket.js : http://www.grideads.net/redmine/attachments/download/113/socket.js 
model.js : http://www.grideads.net/redmine/attachments/download/112/model.js

Comment: Where to start? Please update your question: the formatting is horrible, there is a huge amount of unneccessary code, there is no proper question nor any pre-work or any hint what we should find there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not decode the question, but a possible issue is the way you call your script

```
$.getScript("model.js")
```

http://localhost:8888/  will call http://localhost:8888/model.js

http://localhost:8888/static/ajax.html will call http://localhost:8888/static/model.js

**EDIT**
also your model.js has an error on line 133

```
for( j = 0, jl = meshes.length; j < jl; j++ )
```

the proper for loop format is

```
for (variable=startvalue;variable<=endvalue;variable=variable+increment)
```

j < jl; is extra, resulting in the "Unexpected token <" error message

Comment: I cleared that thing but now I am getting : Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html.
socket.js:1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: you need to fix your server/code settings to serve js files with the "text/javascript" MIME type

Comment: `for( j = 0, jl = meshes.length; j < jl; j++ )` is correct syntax. Initialise the loop setting j to 0 and jl to meshed.length. Check each repetition if j < jl. At the end of each run increment j by one.